# Optimize SQL: How to rewrite this query to boost performance? (Use subqueries, get rid of GROUP BY?)

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization, sql-optimization

I'm using **MySQL 5.7.18-16**.

**Tables that I used:**

```
CREATE TABLE `invoice` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `transaction_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `transaction_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `unit_price` decimal(19,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` decimal(19,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `i_transaction_id` (`transaction_id`),
  KEY `i_date` (`date`)
)


CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `transaction_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
....
)


CREATE TABLE `hierarchy` (
  `PRODUCT_ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `PRODUCT_NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `PRODUCT_FAMILY_ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `PRODUCT_FAMILY_NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ORG_ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ORG_NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL
...
)


CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PRODUCT_NAME` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `COMPONENT_NAME` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
...
)
```

Each invoice record is related to a transaction and a customer name, and each transaction is related to a product and component. Each product will belong to a product family, and each product family will belong to an org.

**Requirements that I Have:**

I need to calculate the cost and quantity for each customer name under different hierarchy levels (org / product family / product / component) based on the invoice date specified, and ORDER BY the cost for each customer name.

**My current query to get cost/quantity for each customer under each org:**

```
SELECT  
    h.org_id,
    h.org_name,
    h.product_family_id,
    h.product_family_name,
    h.product_id,
    h.product_name,
    p.component_id,
    p.component_name,
    i.transaction_id,
    i.customer_name,
    sum(CASE WHEN i.transaction_name = 'TEST' THEN i.quantity END) AS records,
    sum(i.unit_price * i.quantity) AS cost
FROM invoice i
    LEFT JOIN transaction t
        ON i.transaction_id = t.transaction_id
    JOIN hierarchy h
        ON t.product_id = h.product_id
    JOIN product p
        ON t.product_id = p.id
    WHERE i.date >= 1514764800000
    AND i.date <= 1543622400000
    GROUP BY h.org_id, i.customer_name
    ORDER by i.cost DESC;
```

For other levels calculation, I just change the WHERE and GROUP BY:

```
    //By product_family under one specific org
    WHERE h.org_id = 9
    AND i.date >= 1514764800000
    AND i.date <= 1543622400000
    GROUP BY h.product_family_id, i.customer_name
    ORDER by i.cost DESC;

    //By product under one specific product family
    WHERE h.product_family_id = 2011
    AND i.date >= 1514764800000
    AND i.date <= 1543622400000
    GROUP BY h.product_id, i.customer_name
    ORDER by i.cost DESC;

    //By component under one specific product
    WHERE h.product_id = 101
    AND i.date >= 1514764800000
    AND i.date <= 1543622400000
    GROUP BY p.component_name, i.customer_name
    ORDER by i.cost DESC;
```

It took about 3.5s running on production DB for the org level calculation which is too slow. One main reason is that the 'invoice' table is not able to utilize any index. (I created index for 'i.date' but since the date range is too large, the index is not used.)

Are there any possible ways to rewrite this query to optimize the speed?

Comment: Can you update the question to include the database (I assume MySQL) and version being used?

Comment: You are including a bunch of columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`.  That is a malformed query.

Comment: I've updated the MySQL version I used. I know I should include all columns in SELECT in the GROUP BY, but this is not helping the performance which is the main thing that I want to improve right now ;(

Comment: What would these dates be in human readable form?  
    WHERE i.date >= 1514764800000
    AND i.date <= 1543622400000  

Is there any reason you do not use BETWEEN lowdate AND highdate?

Please post TEXT results of EXPLAIN SELECT (rest of your 1st Query).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a view or a cte to get the sum of products per customer then join hierarchy and products to filter and get other infos

```
with customer_products as (
select t.product_id, i.customer_name
    sum(CASE WHEN i.transaction_name = 'TEST' THEN i.quantity END) AS records,
    sum(i.unit_price * i.quantity) AS cost
FROM invoice i
LEFT JOIN transaction t
ON i.transaction_id = t.transaction_id
WHERE i.date >= 1514764800000
AND i.date <= 1543622400000
group by t.product_id, i.customer_name)
SELECT
h.org_id,
    h.org_name,
    h.product_family_id,
    h.product_family_name,
    h.product_id,
    h.product_name,
    p.component_id,
    p.component_name,
    cp.customer_name,
    cp.records,
    cp.cost
FROM customer_products cp
JOIN hierarchy h
ON cp.product_id = h.product_id
JOIN product p
ON cp.product_id = p.id
```

grouping by family

```
SELECT
    h.org_id,
    h.org_name,
    h.product_family_id,
    h.product_family_name,
    cp.customer_name,
    sum(cp.records) as records,
    sum(cp.cost) as cost
FROM customer_products cp
JOIN hierarchy h
ON cp.product_id = h.product_id
JOIN product p
ON cp.product_id = p.id
group by h.org_id,
    h.org_name,
    h.product_family_id,
    h.product_family_name,
    cp.customer_name
```

grouping by component

```
SELECT
h.org_id,
    h.org_name,
    h.product_family_id,
    h.product_family_name,
    p.component_id,
    p.component_name,
    cp.customer_name,
    sum(cp.records) as records,
    sum(cp.cost) as cost
FROM customer_products cp
JOIN hierarchy h
ON cp.product_id = h.product_id
JOIN product p
ON cp.product_id = p.id
group by     h.org_name,
    h.product_family_id,
    h.product_family_name,
    p.component_id,
    p.component_name,
    cp.customer_name
```

or still get all in same query using windowed function

```
SELECT
h.org_id,
    h.org_name,
    h.product_family_id,
    h.product_family_name,
    h.product_id,
    h.product_name,
    p.component_id,
    p.component_name,
    cp.customer_name,
    cp.records,
    cp.cost,
    sum(cp.records) over (partition by h.org_id,
    h.org_name,
    h.product_family_id,
    h.product_family_name,
    cp.customer_name) as familyRecord,
    sum(cp.cost) over (partition by h.org_id,
    h.org_name,
    h.product_family_id,
    h.product_family_name,
    cp.customer_name) as familyCost,
    sum(cp.records) as (parititon by h.org_name,
    h.product_family_id,
    h.product_family_name,
    p.component_id,
    p.component_name,
    cp.customer_name) as componentRecord,
    sum(cp.cost) over (partition by h.org_name,
    h.product_family_id,
    h.product_family_name,
    p.component_id,
    p.component_name,
    cp.customer_name) as costComponent
FROM customer_products cp
JOIN hierarchy h
ON cp.product_id = h.product_id
JOIN product p
ON cp.product_id = p.id
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have updated the table and requirements I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

> Use subqueries

That is generally a worst result than better. As the name states it, the relational databases work well with relations (aka JOINs).

It is most probable the indexes are not set up correctly. In order to show it, there is an `EXPLAIN` command, just write this word at the beginning of the query and see what the optimizer has to tell.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html

It then needs some digging to set the indexes in the schema. You can also paste the EXPLAIN result in your question.